# Segmentation fault when compile assets in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am running ruby 2.1 and rails 3.2.18. I got this error message when i run 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' :

```
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
/home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:99: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0089 p:---- s:0357 e:000356 CFUNC  :Run
c:0088 p:0008 s:0354 e:000353 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:99
c:0087 p:0006 s:0352 e:000351 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/error.rb:84 [FINISH]
c:0086 p:---- s:0348 e:000347 CFUNC  :call
c:0085 p:---- s:0346 e:000345 CFUNC  :TryCatch
c:0084 p:0015 s:0343 E:000af8 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/error.rb:83
c:0083 p:0032 s:0340 E:002330 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:99
c:0082 p:0021 s:0336 e:000335 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:248 [FINISH]
c:0081 p:---- s:0334 e:000333 CFUNC  :call
c:0080 p:---- s:0332 e:000331 CFUNC  :HandleScope
c:0079 p:0015 s:0329 E:000a18 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:245 [FINISH]
c:0078 p:---- s:0327 e:000326 CFUNC  :call
c:0077 p:---- s:0325 e:000324 CFUNC  :Locker
c:0076 p:0041 s:0322 E:001bb0 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:244
c:0075 p:0018 s:0318 e:000317 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:204
c:0074 p:0050 s:0314 E:001e40 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/lib/v8/context.rb:94
c:0073 p:0030 s:0308 e:000307 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:11
c:0072 p:0008 s:0306 e:000305 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78 [FINISH]
c:0071 p:---- s:0303 e:000302 CFUNC  :call
c:0070 p:---- s:0301 e:000300 CFUNC  :Locker
c:0069 p:0023 s:0298 E:000828 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:76
c:0068 p:0020 s:0293 E:0020d8 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:9 [FINISH]
c:0067 p:---- s:0288 e:000287 CFUNC  :new
c:0066 p:0012 s:0283 e:000282 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/runtime.rb:44
c:0065 p:0011 s:0279 e:000278 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/module.rb:27
c:0064 p:0118 s:0275 e:000274 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/uglifier-2.5.3/lib/uglifier.rb:159 [FINISH]
c:0063 p:---- s:0271 e:000270 CFUNC  :new
c:0062 p:0066 s:0268 e:000267 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:32
c:0061 p:0027 s:0263 e:000262 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/bootstrap.rb:18 [FINISH]
c:0060 p:---- s:0261 e:000260 CFUNC  :call
c:0059 p:0025 s:0258 e:000257 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:80
c:0058 p:0007 s:0255 e:000254 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74
c:0057 p:0010 s:0251 e:000250 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265 [FINISH]
c:0056 p:---- s:0247 e:000246 CFUNC  :call
c:0055 p:0016 s:0242 e:000241 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29
c:0054 p:0034 s:0237 e:000236 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103
c:0053 p:0025 s:0231 E:001aa0 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193 [FINISH]
c:0052 p:---- s:0226 e:000225 CFUNC  :each
c:0051 p:0145 s:0223 E:000768 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190
c:0050 p:0097 s:0212 e:000211 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26 [FINISH]
c:0049 p:---- s:0205 e:000204 CFUNC  :new
c:0048 p:0073 s:0199 e:000198 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252
c:0047 p:0014 s:0193 e:000192 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93
c:0046 p:0060 s:0191 e:000190 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19
c:0045 p:0050 s:0185 e:000181 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92
c:0044 p:0088 s:0175 e:000174 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169
c:0043 p:0060 s:0168 e:000167 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60
c:0042 p:0011 s:0160 e:000159 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19
c:0041 p:0030 s:0155 e:000154 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219
c:0040 p:0021 s:0151 e:000150 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206 [FINISH]
c:0039 p:---- s:0148 e:000147 CFUNC  :each
c:0038 p:0080 s:0145 e:000144 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196
c:0037 p:0009 s:0139 E:001770 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204 [FINISH]
c:0036 p:---- s:0136 e:000135 CFUNC  :each
c:0035 p:0027 s:0133 E:0023b8 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203
c:0034 p:0041 s:0130 E:0020d0 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217
c:0033 p:0018 s:0124 E:001920 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18
c:0032 p:0203 s:0120 e:000119 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56
c:0031 p:0007 s:0111 e:000110 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70 [FINISH]
c:0030 p:---- s:0109 e:000108 CFUNC  :call
c:0029 p:0028 s:0104 e:000103 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240 [FINISH]
c:0028 p:---- s:0101 e:000100 CFUNC  :each
c:0027 p:0113 s:0098 e:000097 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235
c:0026 p:0075 s:0094 e:000093 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179
c:0025 p:0014 s:0092 e:000091 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211
c:0024 p:0025 s:0089 e:000088 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172
c:0023 p:0036 s:0082 e:000081 METHOD /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165
c:0022 p:0019 s:0077 e:000076 BLOCK  /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails-3.2.18-cloud-portal/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60 [FINISH]
```

Comment: I have solve this problem.
This is what you can do in Gemfile file
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.3'
Then run bundle update (bundle update therubyracer) command, this will install previous version of therubyracer.

Comment: You should write this as an answer - I'll upvote you for it!

Comment: lol maybe you've done something wrong? Why not go to meta.stackexchange.com to see what the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following, but 'platforms' is obviously optional.

```
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.3', platforms: :ruby
```

There are [several open issues on Github](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20segmentation%20fault).